# Proving a function $B$ satisfies $B(x)=Ax$ for all $x \in D$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ be some bounded linear operator from $D$ to $Y$, and $D\subset X$ be a dense subspace. Let $B$ be defined so that $B(x)=y=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}Ax_n$ for any sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in $D$ converging to $x$.  We know that $\{Ax_n\}_n$ converges and the limit $y$ is unique.

Prove that the function $B$ satisfies $B(x)=Ax$ for all $x \in  D$.

I figured defining a constant infinite series, $xn=x$ for all $n$ would be a start, but I'm not sure where to go from here. This is a course for introduction to real analysis, so any help is much appreciated

Comment: Have you already established that a linear operator on a normed space is continuous if and only if it is bounded?

Comment: I don't think so, no. This sup-problem has really made me scratch my head. We know already that $Y$ is a complete normed vector space and that the operator $B$ is the continuous linear extension of A. Isn't $B$ bounded if it already is continuous? Or is that unclear since we aren't provided with a closed bounded interval?

Comment: Can I use this as a possible solution?:
$B(x)-Ax=\lim_{n\to\infty}Ax_n-Ax=\lim_{n\to\infty}A(x_n-x)=0$